# MVC foreign key binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to set up a project using code first but I have a problem with foreign keys. I have a really simple class with a navigation property. I tried to set the foreign key column name but it isn't working, another column is created instead.

```
public class Point
{
    public int PointId { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public Decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

In the migration file I have :

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Points",
            c => new
                {
                    PointId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    AccountId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Balance = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Account_AccountId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PointId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.AccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.Account_AccountId)
            .Index(t => t.AccountId)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.Account_AccountId);
```

As you can see an `Account_AccountId` column is created but I'd like my `AccountId` column to be used as a foreign key instead.

[Edit]

I've found that some lines that I added in the `OnModelCreating` function are responsible :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Point>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Account)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Account)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

I also specified there which column to use as a foreign key but somehow adding this results in a new column being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to include a parameter in the WithMany method for it to work.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Point>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Account)
            .WithMany(e=> e.Points).HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Account)
            .WithMany(e=>e.Categories).HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```